# Drawing a Parabola Using Two.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, two.js

I want to create a parabola using the library Two.js. Here is the code that I am using:

```js
// Create a Two.js instance
var two = new Two({
  width: 300,
  height: 300
}).appendTo(document.getElementById("parabola"));

var path = two.makePath(0, two.height / 2);

path.stroke = "#000";
path.linewidth = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < two.width; i++) {
  var x = i;
  var y = Math.pow((x - two.width / 2), 2) / (2 * 50) + two.height / 2;
  console.log(`x: ${x} and y: ${y}`);
  path.vertices.push(new Two.Vector(x, y));
}

two.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/two.js/0.8.10/two.min.js"></script>
<div id="parabola"></div>
```

I should draw a parabola that starts at the left end and branches out at the right end. However, the result I get is just two lines.

Am I doing something wrong mathematically or failing to close the path somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You did not close your path.

Also, your `y` calculation is drawing the image too low, and your starting `y` is in the middle.

**Tip:** Try creating a function that returns the `y` coordinate for a given `x`.

```js
// Create a Two.js instance
const two = new Two({ width: 300, height: 300 })
  .appendTo(document.getElementById("parabola"));

const
  xOffset = two.width / 2,
  yOffset = two.height / 2;

const path = two.makePath(0, yOffset);

path.fill = 'red';
path.stroke = "#000";
path.linewidth = 3;

const getY = (x) => (x - xOffset)**2 / yOffset - yOffset;

for (let x = 0; x < two.width; x++) {
  let y = getY(x);
  console.log(`x: ${x} and y: ${y}`);
  path.vertices.push(new Two.Vector(x, y));
}

// Connect the last vertex to the first to close the path...
path.vertices.push(new Two.Vector(0, getY(0)));

two.update();
```

```css
#parabola {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/two.js/0.8.10/two.min.js"></script>
<div id="parabola"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Polywhirl. :) This works as expected. Is there any way for me to prevent the line at the base form being drawn and only draw the curvy part?